# Load index to cache is not using memory available in the key_buffer_size variable

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, cache

Good afternoon folks,

I have a problem when trying to load the indexes from the MyISAM tables into MySQL memory, even though there is space available in the key_buffer_size variable, it stops loading even though there are still indexes to be loaded.

Has anyone had this problem or know what I can do to solve it?

The server that is running the database is a windows server 2012 (¯_(ツ)_/¯ - and don't want to switch to linux server), MySQL is version 5.5.62 and in this instance I have 1210 databases with the structure of the tables in MyISAM.

Below is the configuration file (my.ini):

```
  
  [mysqld] 
   port=3306 
   basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"
   datadir="D:/MySQL/Data/" 
   character-set-server=latin1
   default-storage-engine=myisam
   sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
   max_connections=4500 
   query_cache_size=48M 
   query_cache_type=1
   tmp_table_size = 1G 
   max_heap_table_size = 256M 
   thread_cache_size=1300

   key_buffer_size=62G 
   read_buffer_size = 200M 
   read_rnd_buffer_size = 100M 
   sort_buffer_size = 1G 
   myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096M

  skip-innodb 
  max_allowed_packet=16M 
  interactive_timeout=300
  wait_timeout=1700 
  max_sort_length=4096 
  max_connect_errors=1000000
  table_open_cache=13999 
  table_definition_cache=4096 
  log-warnings
  long_query_time=10 
  open_files_limit=65535 
  slow-query-log
  slow_query_log_file = "D:/MySQL/Data/slowlog.txt" 
  log_output = TABLE
  connect_timeout=30 
  net_read_timeout=65   
  net_write_timeout=65
  tmpdir="D:/MySQL/Temp/"
```

Since there is still a lot of memory available for the cache and most of the scripts are data queries

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
 - for Windows version, - https://github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner -
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added your request for more information as an answer to the [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3362/15356) over on Database Meta Stackexchange. Feel free to add further details to the Meta answer as you see fit. This will allow you to post a "Please read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3362/15356) information regarding MySQL performance issues" to future questions.

Comment: What is the total size of all the `.MYI` files?  How much RAM do you have?  Were you using the `IGNORE LEAVES` option?

Comment: Thank you for the SGS and SGV etc posted. Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com (as a complimentary guest) and share the links. After 24 hours of uptime, from your SSH login root, Text results of: D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report - for Windows version, - github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner  for a more complete workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty strange buffer configuration:

```
max_connections=4500 
. . . . .
key_buffer_size=62G 
read_buffer_size = 200M 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 100M 
sort_buffer_size = 1G 
join_buffer_size = ???
```

While `key_buffer_size` is a global value for all MyISAM indexes across all the databases, `(read|read_rnd|sort|join)_buffer_size` are per-connection values. That amounts are reserved for each client attached to the `mysqld` service. The overall RAM consumption is calculated as:

```
(read_bs + read_rnd_bs + sort_bs + join_bs) * max_connection + key_buffer_size
```

In your case it seems to be at least 6TB in total that is too optimistic.
First you have to lower your buffer sizes to the reasonable values - 2-8MB each. Second you have to install `mysqltuner.pl` - a neat tool that analyze both config and status variables and propose a number of reasonable advices.
Third you have to perform a system monitoring for slow queries and on-disk temporary tables and tune your mysql accordingly to your certain needs.

Answer (score 0):

The server running this MySQL service has 160 GB of ram with an Intel Xeon E5-2697 v3 processor (28 cores)

The HD that is the databases is a Dell 3.2TB, NVMe, Mixed Use Express Flash, HHHL AIC, PM1725b, CK.

The biggest part of the executed processes are selections and insertions.

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE VALUE <> '0' AND VALUE <> '';

- Aborted_clients: 57220
- Aborted_connects: 3131
- Bytes_received: 36040947615
- Bytes_sent: 1360556719043
- Com_admin_commands: 114591
- Com_alter_table: 10367
- Com_begin: 41
- Com_call_procedure: 16716
- Com_change_db: 22594
- Com_commit: 30
- Com_create_db: 7
- Com_create_event: 7
- Com_create_function: 53
- Com_create_index: 14
- Com_create_procedure: 4
- Com_create_table: 4770
- Com_create_trigger: 83
- Com_create_view: 28
- Com_dealloc_sql: 21793
- Com_delete: 1364878
- Com_delete_multi: 26171
- Com_drop_event: 7
- Com_drop_function: 53
- Com_drop_procedure: 2
- Com_drop_table: 4944
- Com_drop_trigger: 532
- Com_drop_view: 62
- Com_empty_query: 3
- Com_execute_sql: 89991
- Com_flush: 2
- Com_insert: 4851225
- Com_insert_select: 145200
- Com_kill: 36366
- Com_load: 1
- Com_lock_tables: 4560
- Com_optimize: 744978
- Com_preload_keys: 50829
- Com_prepare_sql: 90123
- Com_repair: 1
- Com_replace: 12736
- Com_rollback: 12079
- Com_select: 34041572
- Com_set_option: 4462250
- Com_show_charsets: 6
- Com_show_collations: 1543
- Com_show_create_func: 425
- Com_show_create_proc: 341
- Com_show_create_table: 14716
- Com_show_create_trigger: 133
- Com_show_databases: 19734
- Com_show_events: 34
- Com_show_fields: 34238
- Com_show_function_status: 57
- Com_show_keys: 14130269
- Com_show_open_tables: 5
- Com_show_plugins: 3
- Com_show_procedure_status: 57
- Com_show_processlist: 37026
- Com_show_status: 113106
- Com_show_storage_engines: 8
- Com_show_table_status: 4635
- Com_show_tables: 1905693
- Com_show_triggers: 4634
- Com_show_variables: 2123984
- Com_show_warnings: 5
- Com_stmt_close: 2801455
- Com_stmt_execute: 2811106
- Com_stmt_prepare: 2802239
- Com_stmt_reset: 9114
- Com_stmt_send_long_data: 71916
- Com_unlock_tables: 4560
- Com_update: 9011925
- Com_update_multi: 154020
- Compression: OFF
- Connections: 2127954
- Created_tmp_disk_tables: 5655433
- Created_tmp_files: 28847
- Created_tmp_tables: 30958954
- Flush_commands: 1
- Handler_delete: 568112
- Handler_read_first: 6414362
- Handler_read_key: 2702557111
- Handler_read_last: 2655
- Handler_read_next: 3484601325
- Handler_read_prev: 61269195
- Handler_read_rnd: 859438046
- Handler_read_rnd_next: 4123461317
- Handler_update: 301766348
- Handler_write: 1405341275
- Key_blocks_unused: 93494875
- Key_blocks_used: 48795048
- Key_read_requests: 9930039199
- Key_reads: 433621548
- Key_write_requests: 99582766
- Key_writes: 32531990
- Last_query_cost: 0.000000
- Max_used_connections: 4901
- Open_files: 17552
- Open_table_definitions: 19900
- Open_tables: 10900
- Opened_files: 32509588
- Opened_table_definitions: 1185539
- Opened_tables: 4164765
- Prepared_stmt_count: 1
- Qcache_free_blocks: 1713
- Qcache_free_memory: 4755840
- Qcache_hits: 35981931
- Qcache_inserts: 26888989
- Qcache_lowmem_prunes: 20380999
- Qcache_not_cached: 7128110
- Qcache_queries_in_cache: 12672
- Qcache_total_blocks: 31375
- Queries: 138783204
- Questions: 111070732
- Rpl_status: AUTH_MASTER
- Select_full_join: 420042
- Select_full_range_join: 112592
- Select_range: 2109146
- Select_range_check: 1
- Select_scan: 26162353
- Slave_heartbeat_period: 0.000
- Slave_running: OFF
- Slow_queries: 1137
- Sort_merge_passes: 15302
- Sort_range: 54713565
- Sort_rows: 1038439499
- Sort_scan: 4494304
- Ssl_session_cache_mode: NONE
- Table_locks_immediate: 116689300
- Table_locks_waited: 859932
- Threads_cached: 1535
- Threads_connected: 2294
- Threads_created: 10539
- Threads_running: 5
- Uptime: 71170
- Uptime_since_flush_status: 71170

Answer (score 0):

show variables:

- auto_increment_increment: 1
- auto_increment_offset: 1
- autocommit: ON
- automatic_sp_privileges: ON
- back_log: 50
- basedir: C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5.62/
- big_tables: OFF
- binlog_cache_size: 32768
- binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates: OFF
- binlog_format: STATEMENT
- binlog_stmt_cache_size: 32768
- bulk_insert_buffer_size: 8388608
- character_set_client: utf8mb4
- character_set_connection: utf8mb4
- character_set_database: latin1
- character_set_filesystem: binary
- character_set_results: utf8mb4
- character_set_server: latin1
- character_set_system: utf8
- character_sets_dir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
  5.5.62\share\charsets\
- collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
- collation_database: latin1_swedish_ci
- collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci
- completion_type: NO_CHAIN
- concurrent_insert: AUTO
- connect_timeout: 10
- datadir: D:\MySQL\Data\
- date_format: %Y-%m-%d
- datetime_format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
- default_storage_engine: MyISAM
- default_week_format: 0
- delay_key_write: ON
- delayed_insert_limit: 100
- delayed_insert_timeout: 300
- delayed_queue_size: 1000
- div_precision_increment: 4
- engine_condition_pushdown: ON
- error_count: 0
- event_scheduler: ON
- expire_logs_days: 0
- external_user:
- flush: OFF
- flush_time: 1800
- foreign_key_checks: ON
- ft_boolean_syntax: + -><()~*:&|
- ft_max_word_len: 84
- ft_min_word_len: 4
- ft_query_expansion_limit: 20
- ft_stopword_file: (built-in)
- general_log: OFF
- general_log_file: D:\MySQL\Data\dbserver.log
- group_concat_max_len: 1024
- have_compress: YES
- have_crypt: NO
- have_csv: YES
- have_dynamic_loading: YES
- have_geometry: YES
- have_innodb: DISABLED
- have_ndbcluster: NO
- have_openssl: DISABLED
- have_partitioning: YES
- have_profiling: YES
- have_query_cache: YES
- have_rtree_keys: YES
- have_ssl: DISABLED
- have_symlink: YES
- hostname: ServerDB
- identity: 0
- ignore_builtin_innodb: OFF
- init_connect:
- init_file:
- init_slave:
- insert_id: 0
- interactive_timeout: 1901
- join_buffer_size: 4194304
- keep_files_on_create: OFF
- key_buffer_size: 118111600640
- key_cache_age_threshold: 300
- key_cache_block_size: 1024
- key_cache_division_limit: 100
- large_files_support: ON
- large_page_size: 0
- large_pages: OFF
- last_insert_id: 0
- lc_messages: en_US
- lc_messages_dir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5.62\share\
- lc_time_names: en_US
- license: GPL
- local_infile: ON
- lock_wait_timeout: 31536000
- log: OFF
- log_bin: OFF
- log_bin_trust_function_creators: OFF
- log_error: D:\MySQL\Data\dbserver.err
- log_output: TABLE
- log_queries_not_using_indexes: OFF
- log_slave_updates: OFF
- log_slow_queries: ON
- log_warnings: 2
- long_query_time: 10.000000
- low_priority_updates: OFF
- lower_case_file_system: ON
- lower_case_table_names: 1
- max_allowed_packet: 67108864
- max_binlog_cache_size: 18446744073709547520
- max_binlog_size: 1073741824
- max_binlog_stmt_cache_size: 18446744073709547520
- max_connect_errors: 1000000
- max_connections: 4900
- max_delayed_threads: 20
- max_error_count: 64
- max_heap_table_size: 134217728
- max_insert_delayed_threads: 20
- max_join_size: 18446744073709551615
- max_length_for_sort_data: 1024
- max_long_data_size: 67108864
- max_prepared_stmt_count: 16382
- max_relay_log_size: 0
- max_seeks_for_key: 4294967295
- max_sort_length: 4096
- max_sp_recursion_depth: 0
- max_tmp_tables: 32
- max_user_connections: 0
- max_write_lock_count: 4294967295
- metadata_locks_cache_size: 1024
- min_examined_row_limit: 0
- multi_range_count: 256
- myisam_data_pointer_size: 6
- myisam_max_sort_file_size: 2146435072
- myisam_mmap_size: 18446744073709551615
- myisam_recover_options: OFF
- myisam_repair_threads: 1
- myisam_sort_buffer_size: 17179869184
- myisam_stats_method: nulls_unequal
- myisam_use_mmap: OFF
- named_pipe: OFF
- net_buffer_length: 16384
- net_read_timeout: 30
- net_retry_count: 10
- net_write_timeout: 60
- new: OFF
- old: OFF
- old_alter_table: OFF
- old_passwords: OFF
- open_files_limit: 67583
- optimizer_prune_level: 1
- optimizer_search_depth: 62
- optimizer_switch:
  index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on
- performance_schema: OFF
- performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size: 10000
- performance_schema_events_waits_history_size: 10
- performance_schema_max_cond_classes: 80
- performance_schema_max_cond_instances: 1000
- performance_schema_max_file_classes: 50
- performance_schema_max_file_handles: 32768
- performance_schema_max_file_instances: 10000
- performance_schema_max_mutex_classes: 200
- performance_schema_max_mutex_instances: 1000000
- performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes: 30
- performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances: 1000000
- performance_schema_max_table_handles: 100000
- performance_schema_max_table_instances: 50000
- performance_schema_max_thread_classes: 50
- performance_schema_max_thread_instances: 1000
- pid_file: D:\MySQL\Data\serverdb.pid
- plugin_dir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5.62\lib\plugin\
- port: 3987
- preload_buffer_size: 32768
- profiling: OFF
- profiling_history_size: 15
- protocol_version: 10
- proxy_user:
- pseudo_slave_mode: OFF
- pseudo_thread_id: 257434
- query_alloc_block_size: 8192
- query_cache_limit: 1048576
- query_cache_min_res_unit: 4096
- query_cache_size: 67108864
- query_cache_type: ON
- query_cache_wlock_invalidate: OFF
- query_prealloc_size: 8192
- rand_seed1: 0
- rand_seed2: 0
- range_alloc_block_size: 4096
- read_buffer_size: 1048576
- read_only: OFF
- read_rnd_buffer_size: 262144
- relay_log:
- relay_log_index:
- relay_log_info_file: relay-log.info
- relay_log_purge: ON
- relay_log_recovery: OFF
- relay_log_space_limit: 0
- report_host:
- report_password:
- report_port: 3306
- report_user:
- rpl_recovery_rank: 0
- secure_auth: OFF
- secure_file_priv: NULL
- server_id: 0
- shared_memory: OFF
- shared_memory_base_name: MYSQL
- skip_external_locking: ON
- skip_name_resolve: OFF
- skip_networking: OFF
- skip_show_database: OFF
- slave_compressed_protocol: OFF
- slave_exec_mode: STRICT
- slave_load_tmpdir: D:\MySQL\Temp\
- slave_max_allowed_packet: 1073741824
- slave_net_timeout: 3600
- slave_skip_errors: OFF
- slave_transaction_retries: 10
- slave_type_conversions:
- slow_launch_time: 2
- slow_query_log: ON
- slow_query_log_file: D:/MySQL/Data/slowlog.txt
- socket: MySQL
- sort_buffer_size: 2097152
- sql_auto_is_null: OFF
- sql_big_selects: ON
- sql_big_tables: OFF
- sql_buffer_result: OFF
- sql_log_bin: ON
- sql_log_off: OFF
- sql_low_priority_updates: OFF
- sql_max_join_size: 18446744073709551615
- sql_mode:
  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
- sql_notes: ON
- sql_quote_show_create: ON
- sql_safe_updates: OFF
- sql_select_limit: 18446744073709551615
- sql_slave_skip_counter: 0
- sql_warnings: OFF
- ssl_ca:
- ssl_capath:
- ssl_cert:
- ssl_cipher:
- ssl_key:
- storage_engine: MyISAM
- stored_program_cache: 256
- sync_binlog: 0
- sync_frm: ON
- sync_master_info: 0
- sync_relay_log: 0
- sync_relay_log_info: 0
- system_time_zone: E. South America Standard Tim
- table_definition_cache: 19900
- table_open_cache: 10900
- thread_cache_size: 1590
- thread_concurrency: 10
- thread_handling: one-thread-per-connection
- thread_stack: 262144
- time_format: %H:%i:%s
- time_zone: SYSTEM
- timed_mutexes: OFF
- timestamp: 1599168455
- tmp_table_size: 134217728
- tmpdir: D:/MySQL/Temp/
- transaction_alloc_block_size: 8192
- transaction_prealloc_size: 4096
- tx_isolation: REPEATABLE-READ
- unique_checks: ON
- updatable_views_with_limit: YES
- version: 5.5.62-log
- version_comment: MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- version_compile_machine: AMD64
- version_compile_os: Win64
- wait_timeout: 1901
- warning_count: 0

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section,

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=96K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 57,939
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 to reduce key_reads RPS of 6,092
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 for Hot/Warm split to reduce key_reads RPS
key_cache_block_size=16384  # from 1024 to reduce RAM management cycles required
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'key_blocks%' after 2 hours production should show more than 34% used blocks.

Your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS opened_% rates per second could be reduced by raising the limits 10% and making open_tables = open_table_definitions * 1.5 for the count.

For additional assistance, please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch by Skype, please.

Comment: @alexandredelcol Have you had an opportunity to implement the suggestions of Sep 5 at 11:57?  Please comment on results - positive or negative.